# How to create a dynamic cypher query in SDN 5.x similiar to Neo4jOperations in 4.x

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to implement a solution using SDN which was aimed to create a dynamic cypher where my label vary w.r.t input type(n types) irrespective of properties of Node.

Hoping a solultion similiar to what mentioned on this link would help  me. 
[Is it possible to dynamically construct a neo4j cypher query using the GraphRepository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979333/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-construct-a-neo4j-cypher-query-using-the-graphrepo)

I found the below information in Release notes.

Deprecation of Neo4jTemplate
It is highly recommended for users starting new SDN projects to use the OGM Session directly. Neo4jTemplate has been kept to give upgrading users a better experience.

The Neo4jTemplate has been slimmed-down significantly for SDN 4. It contains the exact same methods as Session. In fact Neo4jTemplate is just a very thin wrapper with an ability to support SDN Exception Translation. Many of the operations are no longer needed or can be expressed with a straightforward Cypher query.

If you do use Neo4jTemplate, then you should code against its Neo4jOperations interface instead of the template class.

The following table shows the Neo4jTemplate functions that have been retained for version 4 of Spring Data Neo4j. In some cases the method names have changed but the same functionality is offered under the new version.

To achieve the old template.fetch(entity) equivalent behaviour, you should call one of the load methods specifying the fetch depth as a parameter.

It’s also worth noting that exec(GraphCallback) and the create…​() methods have been made obsolete by Cypher. Instead, you should now issue a Cypher query to the new execute method to create the nodes or relationships that you need.

Dynamic labels, properties and relationship types are not supported as of this version, server extensions should be considered instead.

from this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/

Could anyone help me in achieving the equivalent solution in 
SDN 5.X

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice to use the session directly in place of the Neo4jOperations mechanism.

```
@Autowired 
SessionFactory sessionFactory

public void doCustomQuery() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Iterable<NodeEntity> nodes = session.query(NodeEntity.class, "MATCH (n) RETURN n", params);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should review add some explanation to your code. For more info, checkout this link on [writing good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).